# Test Unit fails to load xsd file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

I have a ruby file that requires a file which has `require 'xsd/qname'`
and all my files work fine, but when I go to test them with test unit I keep getting these errors

```
 LoadError: no such file to load -- xsd/qname
```

I've been scouring google for a while and fail to see a solution. (I'm new to test unit so it might be incredibly simple).

EDIT

I believe my problem is related to the fact that the code is in a gem and not the rails environment, therefore the code using it loads rails while these tests do not.

The odd part is if I go in the gem with irb, I can require `'xsd/qname'`, but I can't require `'soap/rpc/driver'` which is another error I was getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was using files built in ruby 1.8 with 1.9. Using soap4r solved my problem. 
https://github.com/spox/soap4r-spox

Fyi if you just want to just rescue the error do this:

```
begin
  require 'xsd/qname'
rescue LoadError
  puts "xsd/qname not found...."
  exit
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably path related. It's difficult to advise a best solution without seeing how your project is laid out, but try replacing the require statement with:

```
require File.dirname(Rails.root + '/xsd/qname')
```

You may need to adjust that depending on where that file exists within your project.

Comment: I can't touch the file that is requiring qname, but I updated the question.